# How to count Hours and Minutes in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-timestamp

I want to count # of hours worked by subtracting the Start & end time in 1 cell (as per my comp template) ( 9am - 6pm) .( No I can't alter the template to put start & end in different cells/columns)

*I've used this formula now - HOURS()-HOURS(). The problem is it gives me the count only in hours - so 9:00:00 -17:00 gives the result as 8.00 hours **but** if there is half an hour extra it doesn't show as 8.50*

Can you help me understand how I can achieve the right result up-to the minute mark? Thanks

Comment: Welcome. _"No I can't alter the template to put start & end in different cells/columns"_ also _"...if there is half an hour extra it doesn't show as 8.50"_. Please share a test sheet with dummy data and expected results.

Comment: @marikamitsos  Please see this sheet here.[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rS_BJXNcomB2ZuGKC2cq3aDLQTdkMa68qiZargQwg1I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please check the answer and your sheet

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a single cell to input both your data and formula, you should change your *"formula"* from `=HOUR("17:30:00") - Hour("9:00:00")` to simply

```
=("17:30:00" - "9:00:00")*24
```


The above formula will give you the desired result `8.5`.

> **IMPORTANT**. Make sure you format your cells as `Number`
>   *( by going to: `Format` > `Number` > `Number`)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! works perfectly.